# SN. FlatProperties Table Design

Tags: sensenet

I would like to ask about **why** sensenet chooses the following numbers for the number of primitive properties per page:

- nvarchar : 80
- int      : 40
- datetime : 25
- money    : 15

Is it related to sql server max record size whcih is 8 K Bytes?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and at the time when this structure was designed, sql server allowed a limited number of columns too. These numbers are based on the assumption that you'll need text fields mostly and fewer money columns.

But this does not really matter, because there is paging implemented here, so you can register any number of fields in a ctd. If you use more text fields than the number of columns, those values will simply be stored in a new row in the flatproperties table.